# Way to get logon events from remote Windows server without using WMI

Tags: java, windows, winapi, active-directory, wmi

Nowdays my application uses WMIC to poll logon events from remote machine. With WMI i use query like

`-U user%password //myHost '--delimiter="|"' "SELECT eventCode,eventType,timeGenerated,User,InsertionStrings,Message FROM win32_NTLogEvent WHERE Logfile='Security' AND NOT Message LIKE '%$%' AND (eventCode='4624') AND timeGenerated > '20221124190047.000000-000'"`

So server receives query, read `win32_NTLogEvent` object, opens file 'Security', read from it events with code 4624 (which is logon) filter according `timeGenerated` and return me events.

Is there any way to get such information without using WMI?

Comment: WMIC != WMI, Either way, polling is bad...

Comment: @Anders, my application is running on CentOS. There is standart wmic. I use it to get logon events. The question is there any other way to get it without using wmic?